# I want to highlight multiline text come from Api in sync with my speech while reading it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm, next.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HadVj.png)i fetch data from api then display it through map function the text appear in multiline so i want to highlight the text while i reading it through react speech recognition library that convert speech to text i can highlight only one line , i want to highlight line by line finish highlighting the first line then go to the next one using the id of each text if there is a way to detect that i finished reading the first line then increment the id to highlight the next line of text .

i try to increment id manually but i want a way to detect that i have finished reading the first line and move to next line automatically.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.